# Prompt comes up when running report

Tags: report, ms-access-2007

I have created a report from the following query

```
SELECT TasksEntries.Project, TasksEntries.Task, Sum(TimeTracker.WorkHours) AS 
TotalHours
FROM TasksEntries INNER JOIN TimeTracker 
ON (TasksEntries.EmployeeId = TimeTracker.EmployeeId) AND (TasksEntries.TaskID
= TimeTracker.TaskId)
GROUP BY TasksEntries.Project, TasksEntries.Task;
```

The start and end dates are captured from a form and passed like shown below. WorkDate is a column in the TimeTracker table and is not present in any other table.

```
strWhere = "WorkDate BETWEEN #" & txtMgrRptStartDate & "# AND #" &  
txtMgrRptEndDate & "#"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptTotalProjectHours", acViewPreview, 
"qryTotalProjectHours", strWhere, acWindowNormal
```

When the report is invoked, I get a box where it says 
"Enter parameter value" for Workdate.. I am unsure why I get that.

The query runs fine when I run it separately with the start and end dates hard coded in there. The problem seems to occur only when it is passed through the docmd.openreport. Can someone help me get to the bottom of this? When passing the WorkDate thru the OpenReport, is it mandatory that the column name be present in the SELECT statement?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by including the date criteria in the WHERE clause of the SELECT statement and specifying the form text box names of start and end dates.

The other thing that I did was to eliminate the query name from the Docmd.openreport since the report was created from the named query.